# How many usual kinds of translation are there?

Tags: translation

I heard of transliteration, loan translation, and semantics translation. I learned a bit about them by searching on the Internet, but am not completely sure about their relationships and differences.

Are they translation at the levels of letter, morpheme, and word respectively?

I am also wondering how many usual kinds of translation there are?

Comment: Tim, all translation is about translation of meaning in texts or words (bilingual dictionaries) from an A language to a B language. There is no usual kind of translation. It depends on whom your audience is and the purpose of the translation (field, like law, economics, chat messages, etc). Medical questionnaire companies like to do "back-translations" of translated texts as a checking mechanism but they are not usually accurate, which is a kind of "exotic" translation which I call BS. "loan translation" is not really a type. You can however translate loan words literally.